# Why do people set label token's value that has <pad> token to -100 when Language model is pre-trained?

Tags: python, nlp, torch, loss-function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvsUD.png)

Why do people set label token's value that has  token to -100 when Language model is pre-trained? For example, values with pad token in the following figure, are converted to -100.

I think this is for ignoring influence of pad tokens. Then I wonder how the values change when cross-entropy loss is calculated.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

In most case, the tokenizer vocab ID for label is usually positive >0 , and when some code snippet maps a label token to -100, it is to avoid any clashes for an actual vocab ID.

That's why you'll commonly see something like:

```py
def compute_metrics(p):
    predictions, labels = p
    predictions = predictions.argmax(axis=2)
    # Remove ignored index (special tokens)
    true_predictions = [
        [label_list[p] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]
    true_labels = [
        [label_list[l] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]
    results = metric.compute(predictions=true_predictions, references=true_labels)
    return {
        "precision": results["overall_precision"],
        "recall": results["overall_recall"],
        "f1": results["overall_f1"],
        "accuracy": results["overall_accuracy"],
    }
```

To see what are the available token IDs used for particular model, check its tokenizer, e.g.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

min(tokenizer.vocab.values()), max(tokenizer.vocab.values())
```

[out]:

```
(0, 30521)
```

And to see the special token IDs,

```
print(tokenizer.special_tokens_map)
print()

print(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids('[UNK]'))
print(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids('[SEP]'))
print(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids('[PAD]'))
print(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids('[CLS]'))
print(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids('[MASK]'))
```

[out]:

```
{'unk_token': '[UNK]',
 'sep_token': '[SEP]',
 'pad_token': '[PAD]',
 'cls_token': '[CLS]',
 'mask_token': '[MASK]'}

100
102
0
101
103
```

---

For more details, see https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/2?fw=tf

> The first rule we’ll apply is that special tokens get a label of -100. This is because by default -100 is an index that is ignored in the loss function we will use (cross entropy). Then, each token gets the same label as the token that started the word it’s inside, since they are part of the same entity. For tokens inside a word but not at the beginning, we replace the B- with I- (since the token does not begin the entity)

And from Pytorch loss function https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html

```py
torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(
  weight=None, size_average=None, 
  ignore_index=- 100, reduce=None, 
  reduction='mean', label_smoothing=0.0
)
```